# RewriteRule not working on addon domain except for index file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I changed the hosting of a perfectly working website which was an addon domain on one server to an addon domain on another server. Now, the URL rewriting rules are not working except for the `index.php` file.

I have the following codes in the `.htaccess` file out of which only the line:

`RewriteRule ^p/(.*) index.php?p=$1 [L]`

is working and others are not. I contacted the server provider and they confirmed that the modules required for rewriting are installed properly and there's no problem from their end.

What is the error in the code?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) view.php?id=$1&sid=$2&adult=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^go/(.*)/(.*) go.php?usid=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ad/(.*) ad.php?adid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^out/(.*) out.php?sid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^p/(.*) index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^adcode/(.*) adcode.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*) edit.php?sid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^verify/(.*)/(.*) verify.php?id=$1&verify=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem got solved by **changing the file names**.

For instance, I have changed all the file names by adding underscore `_` at the beginning of the file name.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^view/(.*)/(.*)/(.*) _view.php?id=$1&sid=$2&adult=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^go/(.*)/(.*) _go.php?usid=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ad/(.*) _ad.php?adid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^out/(.*) _out.php?sid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^p/(.*) index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^adcode/(.*) _adcode.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/(.*) _edit.php?sid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^verify/(.*)/(.*) _verify.php?id=$1&verify=$2 [L]
```